# How to insert correct value from DropDownList into Database Table

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I have a form where an admin can add a company to a database table called 'Company'

In this form there is a Drop Down list to select whether a company is a Scholarship Company, there are two options 'Yes' and 'No'. I have created a table to pull these options from called 'YesNo'.

When I select Yes in the drop down list and hit submit it updates the table so the cell for ScholarshipCompany is '1' and not 'Yes'. This works fine in the edit form I have which just updates the company though I am having trouble with the add company form which inserts a new entry into the table.

Please see code below;

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Session("Name") = Nothing Then
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")
    End If
    Session("Name") = Session("Name")
    Session("Username") = Session("Username")

    Try

        If Not IsPostBack Then

            Dim locationList As OleDbDataReader = Database.DoSQLReturnDataReader("SELECT [{Location}].ID, [{Location}].Location FROM [{Location}] ORDER BY [{Location}].ID")
            ddlLocation.DataSource = locationList
            ddlLocation.DataTextField = "Location"
            ddlLocation.DataValueField = "ID"
            ddlLocation.DataBind()
            locationList.close()

            Dim statusList As OleDbDataReader = Database.DoSQLReturnDataReader("SELECT *  FROM EmployerStatus  ORDER BY ID ASC")
            ddlStatus.DataSource = statusList
            ddlStatus.DataTextField = "Status"
            ddlStatus.DataValueField = "ID"
            ddlStatus.DataBind()
            statusList.close()

            Dim yesnoList As OleDbDataReader = Database.DoSQLReturnDataReader("SELECT * FROM YesNo ORDER BY ID DESC")
            ddlYesno.DataSource = yesnoList
            ddlYesno.DataTextField = "Option"
            ddlYesno.DataValueField = "Option"
            ddlYesno.DataBind()
            yesnoList.close()

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Redirect("index.aspx?Yr=" & Replace(Request.QueryString("Yr"), "'", "''"))
    End Try
End Sub


Protected Sub BtnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSubmit.Click

    Dim strSql As String = "INSERT INTO Company(" & _
    "CompanyName, " & _
    "URL, " & _
    "Location, " & _
    "EmployerStatus, " & _
    "Address, " & _
    "ScholarshipCompany, " & _
    "ScholarshipNotes, " & _
    "Town, " & _
    "County, " & _
    "Blurb, " & _
    "InterviewTips, " & _
    "HRContactForename, " & _
    "HRContactSurname, " & _
    "HREmail, " & _
    "Telephone, " & _
    "[Password], " & _
    "Fax, " & _
    "HRContactForename2, " & _
    "HRContactSurname2, " & _
    "HREmail2, " & _
    "Telephone2, " & _
    "HRContactForename3, " & _
    "HRContactSurname3, " & _
    "HREmail3, " & _
    "Telephone3, " & _
    "Postcode) " & _
    "VALUES " & _
    "( " & _
    "'" & TxtBoxCompanyName.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "', " & _
    "'" & TxtBoxURL.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "', " & _
    "'" & Replace((ddlLocation.SelectedIndex + 1), "'", "''") & "', " & _
    "'" & Replace((ddlStatus.SelectedIndex + 1), "'", "''") & "', " & _
    "'" & TxtAreaAddress.InnerText.Replace("'", "''") & "', " & _
    "'" & Replace((ddlYesno.SelectedIndex), "'", "''") & "', " & _
    "'" & TxtBoxSchol.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "', " & _
    "'" & TxtBoxTown.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "', " & _
    "'" & TxtBoxCounty.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "', " & _
    "'" & "" & "', " & _
    "'" & "" & "', " & _
    "'" & "" & "', " & _
    "'" & "" & "', " & _
    "'" & "" & "', " & _
    "'" & "" & "', " & _
    "'" & "" & "', " & _
    "'" & "" & "', " & _
    "'" & "" & "', " & _
    "'" & "" & "', " & _
    "'" & "" & "', " & _
    "'" & "" & "', " & _
    "'" & "" & "', " & _
    "'" & "" & "', " & _
    "'" & "" & "', " & _
    "'" & "" & "', " & _
    "'" & TxtBoxPostcode.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "'" & _
    ")"

    Dim updateCompanyDetails As OleDbDataReader = Database.DoSQLReturnDataReader(strSql)
    updateCompanyDetails.Close()
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep("1000")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

`Replace((ddlLocation.SelectedIndex + 1), "'", "''") & "', " & _
 "'" & Replace((ddlStatus.SelectedIndex + 1), "'", "''") & "', " & _`

try

`Replace((ddlLocation.SelectedValue + 1), "'", "''") & "', " & _
    "'" & Replace((ddlStatus.SelectedValue + 1), "'", "''") & "', " & _`

or SelectedText